# Quickly filter down a grid of sf points according to a polygon

Tags: r, optimization, r-sf

I want to make grids (in the sense of data frames of *x*- and *y*-coordinates) over the US, or regions of the US, throwing out any points in the original grid that are beyond the borders of the US. I have some code that seems to work, but it's quite slow when I shrink the grid increment down to 1 km (`1e3`) or so. How can this be done faster? Perhaps there's a way to build the simple feature collection that I need without a `lapply` or loop, or perhaps this can be done with a `MULTIPOINT` instead of a simple feature collection of `POINT`s.

```
library(sf)

crs.us.atlas = 2163 # https://epsg.io/2163

us = read_sf(paste0("/vsizip/",
    "/tmp/us.zip")) # from: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2019/shp/cb_2019_us_state_500k.zip
# Filter down to the lower 48 + DC.
us = us[us$STUSPS %in% setdiff(c(state.abb, "DC"), c("AK", "HI")),]
us = st_transform(us, crs = crs.us.atlas)
l = as.list(st_bbox(us))

increment = 1e5

g = expand.grid(
    x = seq(l$xmin, l$xmax, by = increment),
    y = seq(l$ymin, l$ymax, by = increment))

message("Running the slow part")
print(system.time(g <- g[0 < sapply(FUN = length, st_intersects(
    st_as_sfc(crs = crs.us.atlas, lapply(1 : nrow(g), function(i)
        st_point(as.numeric(g[i, c("x", "y")])))),
    us)),]))

print(nrow(g))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sf` has a function `st_make_grid` that could help with this (in older versions of `sf`, it even automatically cropped to the polygon), but curiously, it's [quite slow](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1579) as of this writing.

I can get reasonable performance without additional dependencies by using `st_as_sf` to convert `g` to a simple feature collection of points:

```
g = st_as_sf(crs = crs.us.atlas, coords = c(1, 2), g)
```

Then, following @agila's use of `unlist`, the slow part becomes

```
print(system.time(g <- g[unlist(st_intersects(us, g)),]))
```

which, with `increment = 1e3`, takes 3 minutes on a high-end server.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve the problem as follows. First, load the packages. `tmap` is used just for the map, you can easily ignore that

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
library(sfheaders)
library(tmap)
```

Download and read-in data

```r
temp_zip <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
download.file(
  "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2019/shp/cb_2019_us_state_500k.zip", 
  destfile = temp_zip
)
unzip(temp_zip, exdir = tempdir())
us <- st_read(file.path(tempdir(), "cb_2019_us_state_500k.shp"))
#> Reading layer `cb_2019_us_state_500k' from data source `C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCakscO\cb_2019_us_state_500k.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 56 features and 9 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -179.1489 ymin: -14.5487 xmax: 179.7785 ymax: 71.36516
#> geographic CRS: NAD83
```

Filter down to the lower 48 + DC.

```r
us = us[us$STUSPS %in% setdiff(c(state.abb, "DC"), c("AK", "HI")),]
us = st_transform(us, crs = 2163)
```

Define increment, grid and `sfc` object. The key part is to create and `sfc_point` object for subsequent operations

```r
increment = 1e5
g = expand.grid(
  x = seq(st_bbox(us)$xmin, st_bbox(us)$xmax, by = increment),
  y = seq(st_bbox(us)$ymin, st_bbox(us)$ymax, by = increment)
)
g_sfc <- sfc_point(as.matrix(g)) %>% 
  st_set_crs(2163)
```

Find the ID(s) of points included in the US

```r
my_ids <- unlist(st_contains(us, g_sfc))
```

Visualise result

```r
tm_shape(g_sfc) + 
  tm_dots(col = "grey", size = 0.05) + 
tm_shape(g_sfc[my_ids]) + 
  tm_dots(col = "darkred", size = 0.05) + 
tm_shape(us) + 
  tm_borders(lwd = 1.3)
```

[image]

Repeat for 1e3 (but I won't add any plot since that's almost 13 million points)

```
increment = 1e3
g = expand.grid(
  x = seq(st_bbox(us)$xmin, st_bbox(us)$xmax, by = increment),
  y = seq(st_bbox(us)$ymin, st_bbox(us)$ymax, by = increment)
)
```

It takes approximately 20 seconds to generate the data

```r
system.time({
  g_sfc <- sfc_point(as.matrix(g)) %>% 
    st_set_crs(2163)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   16.29    0.92   17.27
```

and 80 seconds to find the IDs of the points within US.

```r
system.time({
  my_ids <- unlist(st_contains(us, g_sfc))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   67.75    8.32   80.86
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you need something even more efficient, I suggest you [`polyclip`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polyclip/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use the `fasterize` package to create a raster grid around the shape file with your desired resolution and then extract the grid coordinates using the `raster::rasterToPoints` function.

This works almost immediately for gathering the xy locations. To convert back to an sf object then takes about 10 seconds or so.

```
library(sf)
library(fasterize)
library(raster)

crs.us.atlas = 2163

# https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2019/shp/cb_2019_us_state_500k.zip
us = read_sf(list.files(pattern='.shp$'))
us = us[us$STUSPS %in% setdiff(c(state.abb, "DC"), c("AK", "HI")),]
us = st_transform(us, crs = crs.us.atlas)

increment = 1e3

# create the empty raster to for fasterize base
usrast = raster::raster(us, resolution=rep(increment, 2))

# rasterize the shapefile
r = fasterize::fasterize(us, usrast)

# extract raster cell coordinates
coords = rasterToPoints(r)

# convert coordinates to sf
shp = coords %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    st_as_sf(crs=crs.us.atlas, coords=c('x', 'y'))
```

[image]